# How MediaCodec finds the codec inside the framework in Android?

Tags: android, android-internet, stagefright, openmax, opencore

I am trying to understanding how MediaCodec is used for hardware decoding.

My knowledge in android internal is very limited.

**Here is my findings:**

There is a xml file which represents the codec details in the android system .

```
 device/ti/omap3evm/media_codecs.xml for an example.
```

Which means, that If we create a codec from the Java Application with Media Codec

```
MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
```

It should be finding out respective coder with the help of xml file.

**What am I  doing?**

I am trying to figure our which part of the code is reading xml and find the codec based on given 'type'.

1)   Application Layer :

```
   MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
```

2)   MediaCodec.java  ->  [ **frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java**  ]

```
     public static MediaCodec createDecoderByType(String type) {

    return new MediaCodec(type, true /* nameIsType */, false /* encoder */);
}
```

3)

```
private MediaCodec(
        String name, boolean nameIsType, boolean encoder) {
    native_setup(name, nameIsType, encoder);    --> JNI Call.
}
```

4) 
JNI Implementation -> [ **frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp** ]

```
static void android_media_MediaCodec_native_setup (..) {
        .......
    const char *tmp = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, NULL);
    sp<JMediaCodec> codec = new JMediaCodec(env, thiz, tmp, nameIsType, encoder);     ---> Here
}
```

from frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp

```
    JMediaCodec::JMediaCodec( ..) { 
         .... 
          mCodec = MediaCodec::CreateByType(mLooper, name, encoder); //Call goes to libstagefright 
          .... }


    sp<MediaCodec> MediaCodec::CreateByType(
            const sp<ALooper> &looper, const char *mime, bool encoder) {
        sp<MediaCodec> codec = new MediaCodec(looper);
        if (codec->init(mime, true /* nameIsType */, encoder) != OK) {  --> HERE.
            return NULL;
        }    
    return codec;
   }



    status_t MediaCodec::init(const char *name, bool nameIsType, bool encoder) {
           // MediaCodec
    }
```

I am struck with this flow. If someone points out how to take it forward would help a lot.

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's take the flow step by step.

1. `MediaCodec::CreateByType` will create a new `MediaCodec` object
2. `MediaCodec` constructor would create a new `ACodec` object and store it as `mCodec`
3. When `MediaCodec::init` is invoked, it internally instructs the underlying `ACodec` to allocate the `OMX` component through [`mCodec->initiateAllocateComponent`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodec.cpp#947).
4. `ACodec::initiateAllocateComponent` would invoke [`onAllocateComponent`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp#3578)
5. `ACodec::UninitializedState::onAllocateComponent` would invoke `OMXCodec::findMatchingCodecs` to find the codecs matching the `MIME` type passed from the caller.
6. In `OMXCodec::findMatchingCodecs`, there is a call to retrieve an instance of `MediaCodecList` as [`MediaCodecList::getInstance()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#189).
7. In `MediaCodecList::getInstance`, there is a check if there is an existing `MediaCodecList` or else [a new object of `MediaCodecList` is created](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#43).
8. In the constructor of `MediaCodecList`, there is a call to [`parseXMLFile`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#58) with the file name as `/etc/media_codecs.xml`.
9. `parseXMLFile` reads the contents and stores the different component names etc into `MediaCodecList` which can be used for any other codec instance too. The helper function employed for the parsing is [`startElementHandler`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#172) . A function of interest could be [`addMediaCodec`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#309).

Through these steps, the `XML` file contents are translated into a list which can be employed by any other module. `MediaCodecList` is exposed at **Java** layer too as can be referred from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecList.html).

I have skipped a few hops wherein `MediaCodec` and `ACodec` employ messages to actually communicate and invoke methods, but the flow presented should give a good idea about the underlying mechanism.

Comment: Impressive Ganesh!!. Thanks for help.